# How do I get UNR back and ditch Unity in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

Is there any way to get the old Ubuntu Netbook Remix UI back in 10.10 and ditch Unity, which while it might be nice for some people (I'm unconvinced) is completely inefficient and horrible for other use cases.

Answer (score 1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1592045 suggests that the old package is now named netbook-launcher-efl

Comment: I switched from Unity back to the netbook remix UI on 11.04 and sure enough, the package I needed was netbook-launcher-efl, not netbook-launcher.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get remove unity --yes && sudo apt-get autoremove --yes && sudo apt-get install netbook-launcher --yes`

Comment: Which would be great if netbook-launcher on 10.10 didn't reinstall unity and thus leave me exactly where I started.

Comment: Hm... is there anything stopping you from jumping back to 10.04 though?

Comment: Well, there's no clean process for doing so, but it's probably what I'll end up doing.  That being said, Unity is just an X application, it seems insane that I have to downgrade my entire OS to change my desktop environment.

Comment: And hence, Ubuntu is the new mac. ;-)